# Unlock bootloader on cm12

Tags: cyanogenmod, bootloader-lock

I'm now having a Samsung Galaxy Superior (GT-I9260) running on cm12.1 downloaded from the [cm website](https://download.cyanogenmod.org/). I want to flash it to kali linux now, and it tells me to unlock the bootloader first. After doing some research, I found out that people suggest some commands like `adb reboot bootloader` and `fastboot oem unlock`. But I just cant boot into the bootloader, even if I'm booting it from the recovery using the option `reboot bootloader`. My problem is, is that my bootloader has been unlocked, or I need some other ways to make it work?

Note: I'm currently using a linux computer.

Comment: What about long pressing Home + Power + Volume down when device is powered off? ([Source](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Superior_Info)) It is called download mode in Samsung devices.

Comment: it enters the download mode immediately, and shows odin mode. and then I cannot use either `adb` or `fastboot`.

Comment: How is flashing an Android phone to Kali Linux even possible? Where did you get that idea? it won't work at all. Even if Kali did support ARM processors like that of your phone, it wouldn't work because of incompatibilities with other hardware in your phone. What is the guide you were planning on using to do this?

Comment: Also, most Samsung devices don't have a specific `fastboot` mode, you'll have to use the ODIN PC program to access the device in download mode and flash stuff, once you have the correct drivers installed on your PC.

Comment: Thanks. And the idea is from [here](https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-nethunter-download/)